# retrying a code with minor changes until it works in python

Tags: python-3.x, loops, try-catch

How can I retry a code with the `try` function? 
Idea is:

```
try:
interaction_type2 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('web.page.interaction1')
except Error:
interaction_type2 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('web.page.interaction2')
```

each time it should add to the interaction +1 and loop through it until there is no error, so try to execute the code each time until it does it successfully.
I tried it with a loop but did not get the outcome I want to have.

The code I have so far:

```
    while True:
    x = 'web.page.interaction-70"]'
    try:
        interaction_type2 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(x) # next 136 then 202, 268
    except Exception:
        x = x.replace('70', '138')
        interaction_type2 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(x)
    interaction_type2.click()
```

not sure how I can change that on each error, without writing each line.

Comment: A loop is the thing to use. Show us the loop you wrote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can substitute in each value as needed.

```
for value in [70, 136, 202, 268]:
    x = f'web.page.interaction-{value}"]'
    try:
        interaction_type2 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(x)
    except Exception:
        continue
    else:
        interaction_type2.click()
        break
```

If you need to keep trying values beyond 268, take a look at `itertools.count`. You'd loop over `itertools.count(start=70, step=66)`. This may be dangerous, though, if every single request fails, giving an infinite loop. You may want to bound your search by instead using `range(70, some_high_value, 66)`.

Comment: Thank you, from a logical perspective this should solve my problem, however, I get now the error message that a 'list' object doesn't have the click attribute (I'm using selenium)

Comment: This really ought to be asked as a separate question. But if you're certain that there's one element matching this description, switch from `find_elements_by_xpath` to `find_element_by_xpath`. (Note the 's' that is removed.)

Comment: Hi @Ochitsuku, did this answer your question? If so, I'd appreciate if you marked the green check next to it. It makes it easier for others to find a trusted solution to this problem.

Comment: I still have to play with it, @Arya McCarthy 
So far it did not solve my problem, but I think I might be able to get it solved with your info :)